# Compare XML files to determine differences

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I've been looking around, and though there are several options, none of them really fit my current problem.

I get two XML files, File1 and File2 that have "User" nodes with childnodes detailing things like name, age, address, etc. From there I need to create a third XML File3 that exclusively contains the fields that have changed between the two while keeping the "name" node to identify that the change was done with that user.

So if I get:

```
File 1:
<users>
 <user>
  <name>Marco</name>
  <height>1,76</height>
  <address>C:/ Far-away 34</address>
  <mail>marco@marco</mail>
 </user>
</users>

File 2:
<users>
 <user>
  <name>Marco</name>
  <height>1,80</height>
  <address>C:/ Far-away 34</address>
  <mail></mail>
 </user>
</users>
```

It should spit out an XML with:

```
File 3:
<users>
 <user>
  <name>Marco</name>
  <height>1,80</height>
  <mail></mail>
 </user>
</users>
```

With one of my main complications being that I am not told which nodes will be present (or whether or not they have childnodes) other than "name".

EDIT: Users only show up once, nodes can be in any order, number of nodes isn't fixed.

Comment: You need to define how intelligent this needs to be. Can the sub-elements be in any order? Can there be multiple users named Marco? Can there be multiple sub-elements named 'mail'? etc. If an element is missing in the 2nd file, how does it handle that?

Comment: Need more example data to do this correctly.  Have done similar tasks in the past.  I agree with Chuck except that just answering his question usually isn't sufficient.  See the actual input is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [XElement class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/xelement-class-overview).

Deserialize your XMLs into XElement objects and then you can compare childnodes one by one.

If you know all possible nodes that might appear in this XMLs you can deserialize this XMLs directly into C# objects. But with XElement class you can implement more generic solution.